# PostOrder output in a generic BinarySearchTree (Java)

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree, postorder

I'm having a little trouble with some coding Homework. I'm supposed to write a Generic Binary Search Tree Utility, including a method for returning an ArrayList of the postOrder traversion of the Tree. My Code compiles, but it throws a NullPointerException for all but empty trees. Where's my mistake?

```
public ArrayList<T> postOrder(BinarySearchTree<T> tree) {
    if (tree == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        ArrayList<T> post = new ArrayList<T>();
        post.addAll(postOrder(tree.left));
        post.addAll(postOrder(tree.right));
        post.add(tree.thing);
        return post;
    }
}
```

The class BinarySearchTree is:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T> {
/**
 * The key by which the thing is refered to. Must be unique.
 */
public int key;

/**
 * The thing itself.
 */
public T thing;

/**
 * The left sub-tree
 */
public BinarySearchTree<T> left;

/**
 * The right sub-tree
 */
public BinarySearchTree<T> right;
Biny
/**
 * Create a new binary search tree without children.
 * @param key the key by which the thing is refered to
 * @param thing the new thing
 */
public BinarySearchTree(int key, T thing)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.thing = thing;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

/**
 * Create a new binary search tree
 * @param key the key by which the thing is refered to
 * @param thing the thing which is managed by the new binary search tree
 * @param left the left sub-tree of the new binary search tree
 * @param right the right sub-tree of the new binary search tree
 */
public BinarySearchTree(int key, T thing, BinarySearchTree<T> left, BinarySearchTree<T> right)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.thing = thing;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}
```

Thanks for Helping

Edit: I'm testing my Code with Strings, but that hopefully shouldn't matter because of the Generic Types used.

Comment: What line gives you the NPE?

Comment: When you descend to the end of your recursion, at a leaf node, `postOrder()` will return `null` for each of that node's children, right?  What do you think happens when you pass that to `post.addAll()`?

Comment: Consider returning an empty `List` instead of `null` when the argument is `null`.

Comment: The Line: post.addAll(postOrder(tree.left));

Comment: I was thinking it wold just add nothing to the ArrayList, but that does seem like something to try out

Comment: I just tested your Suggestion and replacing the: ` return null;`  with:  `return new ArrayList<T>();` seems to do the trick, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ArrayList<T> postOrder(BinarySearchTree<T> tree) {
    if (tree == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        ArrayList<T> post = new ArrayList<T>();
        ArrayList<T> l = postOrder(tree.left);
        if (l != null) post.addAll(l);
        ArrayList<T> r = postOrder(tree.right);
        if (r != null) post.addAll(r);
        post.add(tree.thing);
        return post;
    }
}
```